# android INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android, eclipse, android-widget, snmp

That problem comes with snmp4android.jar using Android 3.1

```
[2013-04-08 14:42:25 - ControlloGiardinoWG] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2013-04-08 14:42:25 - ControlloGiardinoWG] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-04-08 14:42:25 - ControlloGiardinoWG] Launch canceled!
```

on logat:

```
package ..... requires unavaiable shared library org.snmp4j.CommunityTarget; failing!
```

but package was added on build path, tried to also add on libs, tried to also add on assets, tried to clean and build project on every tries...

on manifest i've declared all used libraries:

```
 <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.CommunityTarget"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.PDU"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.Snmp"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.TransportMapping"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.event.ResponseEvent"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.event.ResponseListener"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.mp.SnmpConstants"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.smi.Address"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.smi.GenericAddress"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.smi.Integer32"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.smi.OID"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.smi.OctetString"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.smi.UdpAddress"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.smi.VariableBinding"/>
        <uses-library android:name="org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping"/>
```

tried to remove and reinstall sdk...
where could be the problem?

Comment: Solved... The problem comes up because for external jars its not required to declare library on manifest... Deleting on manifest the `<uses-library>` writed on the post solves the problem...

Comment: Add it to answer and accept it. Helpful for someother

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved... The problem comes up because for external jars its not required to declare library on manifest... Deleting on manifest the  writed on the post solves the problem...